# Having trouble when using 2d orthographic matrix with glm

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, projection, glm-math

after I've set up the (orthogonal) projection matrix for my simple 2d game, nothing renders on the screen. I am using cglm (glm but in c) and compared the results of cglm with the normal glm ortho projection implementation that renders well, and the results of the projection matrix match. Here is my render loop:

```c
void RenderSprite(const struct Sprite *sprite) {

    struct Shader *shader = GetSpriteShader(sprite);
    UseShader(shader);

    /* cglm starts here */
    mat4 proj;
    glm_ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, proj); /* screen width: 800, height: 600 */

    mat4 model;
    glm_mat4_identity(model); /* an identity model matrix - does nothing */
    /* cglm ends here */

    SetShaderUniformMat4(shader, "u_Projection", proj); /* set the relevant uniforms */
    SetShaderUniformMat4(shader, "u_Model", model);

    /* finally, bind the VAO and call the draw call (note that I am not using batch rendering - I am using just a simple plain rendering system) */
    glBindVertexArray(ezGetSpriteVAO(sprite));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ezGetSpriteIndexCount(sprite), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

However, this results in a blank screen - nothing renders. I believe I've did everything in order - but the problem is nothing renders.
For anyone interested, here is my vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 u_Model;
uniform mat4 u_Projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_Projection * u_Model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
}
```

And here is my fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0f);
}
```

As far as I am aware, cglm matrices are ordered column-major, which OpenGL wants.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The sprite coordinates are (in this case it is the vertex data, I guess):

```c
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f
```

**EDIT 2**
After @BDL's comment, I have adjusted the vertex data as following:

```c
float vertices[] = {
        /*   Position       UV */
            5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// bottom left
            10.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
            10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top right
            5.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
};
```

But, I can't see anything on the screen - nothing is being rendered at this point.

Comment: Please show the coordinates you are trying to render. Are they simply outside the visible area?

Comment: The coordinates are: 
           -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f

Comment: Your projection matrix goes from 0,0 to 800,600. The quad has a size of 1x1 (aka, 1 pixel). Did you check if there is a colored pixel in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Dang! I forgot to edit the vertex coordinates to suit the proj matrix! I will now edit them and post a comment asap. Thanks

Comment: Well, I have now made the coordinates as following:   
  float vertices[] = {
            /*   Position       UV */
            -10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// bottom left
            10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
            10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top right
            -10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
    };
But, still nothing  is being rendered :(

Comment: Your project matrix mirrors the Y-axis which means that it also changes the winding order. Depending on the indices, backface culling might eliminate your geometry. Also note that your visible range goes from 0 to 800 (on X-axis). 3/4th or your quad from -10 to 10 will be outside of the visible area.

Comment: Well, my indices array is 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3. And following your comment, I have adjusted the vertices (again), and you can see it in the original post as an edit. Also, I didn't know that the matrix was mirroring the Y-axis, is it because the params are specified as 0, 800, 600, 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BDL and others have suggested, here is my final render loop that works like a charm right now:
(posting as a reference)

```c
void RenderSprite(const struct Sprite *sprite) {
    ASSERT(sprite, "[ERROR]: Can't render a sprite which is NULL\n");

    struct Shader *shader = GetSpriteShader(sprite);
    UseShader(shader);

    mat4 proj;
    glm_ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, proj);
    mat4 model, view;
    glm_mat4_identity(model);
    glm_mat4_identity(view);

    SetShaderUniformMat4(shader, "u_Projection", proj);
    SetShaderUniformMat4(shader, "u_Model", model);
    SetShaderUniformMat4(shader, "u_View", view);

    glBindVertexArray(GetSpriteVAO(sprite));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, GetSpriteIndexCount(sprite), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

And here are my coordinates:

```c
float vertices[] = {
           /*   Position       UV */
       350.0f, 350.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// bottom left
       450.0f, 350.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
       450.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top right
       350.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
};
```

Also here are my shaders:

```c
const char *default_vs = "#version 330 core\n"
                         "layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n"
                         "layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;\n"
                         "uniform mat4 u_Model;\n"
                         "uniform mat4 u_Projection;\n"
                         "uniform mat4 u_View;\n"
                         "void main() {\n"
                         "    gl_Position = u_Projection * u_View * u_Model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);\n"
                         "}";

const char *default_fs = "#version 330 core\n"
                         "out vec4 color;\n"
                         "void main() {\n"
                         "    color = vec4(1.0f);\n"
                         "}";
```

Hope this helps anyone that is having the same problem!